# AWS architecture Account migration strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I will soon be asked to migrated an AWS architecture, including instances' content and DB records from one AWS account to another and I would like to hear from you all how would you define a possible strategy to tackle it:

Say we have 2 AWS accounts (A1, A2). A1 was used as Proof of Concept to decide weather or not to adopt AWS as cloud provider for my organisation and will soon be dismissed. A2 is the new "proper" account of the organisation and it will used from now on. Different environments will be create in it, one for each development stage (Dev, QA, Prod).

In A1 account I manually created an architecture very similar to this https://github.com/awslabs/aws-refarch-wordpress/blob/master/images/aws-refarch-wordpress-v20171026.jpeg. Say the only difference is that instead of WordPress we used the CMS my organisation adopted.

The web publishing team started than to use the CMS and populated it with content.

Given that the EC2 instances are configured to use EFS as shared file system, the content is now distributed as following:
- EC2 EBS storage contains the core of the CMS and zero configuration or file produced by the web publishing team or users
- EFS contains CMS configuration, user uploaded file, CMS plugins and every file that is not part of the core of CMS
- RDS contains the records

To migrate everything, I would like now to create a AWS CloudFormation template of the architecture (useful also to move the architecture from one stage to other) and create an AMI of the EC2 and use it in the template (as part of the AutoScaling group Launch configuration).

How would you approach the migration of the "dynamic" part of the architecture (EFS file system and RDS database record)? 
Would you go with the restore of 2 snapshots (previously taken from the current architecture) during the creation of the stack? 
How would you technically implement it?

Thank you in advance for the discussion.